# Filter blog posts

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

1st of all I'm using version 7.3.3 with fanoe starter kit. I am trying to find the best and not that hard way to filter the blog post by some "options" that i have Created. I have created new properties on the "blog spot" document type. one is "Country" and the second one is "Project type" i managed to get the existing values on both of them and place then on even get the selected value by javascript by I'm stack on the filtering of the data. have a look at what i have added to the "Blog Overview" template.

```
  @{ 
                var posts = CurrentPage.Children;
                var usedcountries = new List<string>();
                var usedProjectTypes = new List<string>();
            }
            <div class="col-sm-3">

                    @foreach (var post in posts)
                    {
                        if (!usedcountries.Contains(post.countries))
                        {
                            usedcountries.Add(post.countries);
                        };

                    }
                    @{usedcountries.Sort();}

                <select id="theCountry">
                    <option value="none">Any Country</option>
                    @foreach (var c in usedcountries)
                    {
                        <option value="@c">@c</option>
                    }
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">

                    @foreach (var post in posts)
                    {
                        if (!usedProjectTypes.Contains(post.projectType))
                        {
                            usedProjectTypes.Add(post.projectType);
                        };
                    }
                    @{usedProjectTypes.Sort();}

                <select id="theType">
                    <option value="none">Any Project Type</option>
                    @foreach (var p in usedProjectTypes)
                    {
                        <option value="@p">@p</option>
                    }
                </select>

            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <button onclick="sendAndReloadFunction()">Search</button>

                </div>

        </div>
```

FYI - i still don't know much about XSLT.. i know Linq and maybe an API solution might fit.. but I might be wrong.,. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Does the above code work? Does it give any errors? Or are you just interested in how to refactor this?

Comment: the code above works and makes good option boxes. But my problem is how i'm going to bring the results after the selection is made.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco supports multiple ways of posting data back to the server.

The first one is through a [surface controller](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/surface-controllers), this works similar to mvc controllers

Another way is using umbraco's [web api](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/), this I would use when posting from javascript